# How to output elements from table if they are consecutive integers

Tags: php, sql, database, algorithm, logic

I have the following table in a database:

[image: Table with slotID and isFree]

I have a variable `$slotsNeeded` which is the number of **consecutive** `slotID` with `isFree = true` needed from the table. How may I output all of the possible combinations using `echo`, up to a maximum of 5?

For example:

- When `$slotsNeeded = 1` output should be `echo 1."<br>".3."<br>".4."<br>".5."<br>".7; // Maximum 5 combinations`
- When `$slotsNeeded = 2` output should be `echo 3, 4."<br>".4, 5."<br>".7, 8;`
- When `$slotsNeeded = 3` output should be `echo 3, 4, 5;`

I have tried everything but can't seem to find a solution. Please advise. Thank you.

Edit: my actual table was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE $tbl_Appts (
        slotID INTEGER(255) PRIMARY KEY,
        time TIME,
        patientID BIGINT,
        bedID INTEGER(255),
        isFree BOOLEAN DEFAULT 1,
    )
```

And currently looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can find the first of a series of available slots using `lead()`.  To get five in a row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(slotId, 4) over (partition by isFree order by slotId) as slotId_4
      from $tbl_Appts t
      where isFree = 'True'
     ) t
where slotId_4 = slotId + 4;
```

The `lead()` looks at the row 4 rows ahead where `isFree` is true.  If that row is the current slot plus 4, then all the intermediate rows are `true` and you have 5 in a row.

Comment: Could you add comments to help me understand this a little better, please? I'm new to SQL and unfamiliar with most of the key terms. Thank you so much!

Comment: Additionally, I have added a screenshot of my actual table to the original post. How might I use what you've written in this case, using my ```$slotsNeeded``` variable? Thank you!

Comment: @bob . . . You would adjust the "4" to be based on the `$slotsNeeded` (hint:  subtract 1).

Comment: What does ```select t.*``` mean? How might I apply this code specifically to my table ```$tbl_Appts```? Thank you.

Comment: @Bob . . . It just selects all the columns form the table or column alias specified by `t`.